# Total curent through two parallel resistors

Tags: voltage, current, parallel

[image]

`voltage source- 5V`

This simulator shows that the curent in the left wire will be 10A, like sum of curents through two parallel resistors. Is it wrong?

Comment: Ohms law? Do you understand it?

Answer (score 0):

If the two 1 ohm resistors are identical and the wires used to hook them up to the circuit are identical then the current will split with half passing through each of the resistors (5A in each resistor).

Answer (score 0):

The simulation is showing the total current of the circuit. Since the resistors are in parallel,their effective resistance is 1*1/2 =0.5 ohms.

So according to ohms law the current will be I = V/R i.e 5/0.5 = 10A

Comment: 1*1/2 - is some specific formula? What if resistance will be different, and what if there will be another not parallel resistor?

Comment: @Artur The general formula for parallel resistors is \$\frac{1}{1/R_1 + 1/R_2 + ... + 1/R_n}\$.

Comment: @Felthry it is a resistance of a single resistor?

Answer (score 0):

The simulation is correct.

Voltage Supplied: 5V

Total Impedance: (1+1)^(-1) =.5ohms

Thus, 5V/.5ohms = 10A

With 5A going through each resistor due to equal resistances